# Using Executer in a daemon process

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

We have a daemon process which has to execute everytime and look for the new request to process.Since we have 5 servers where we need to execute the process, current daemon process is creating 5 threads by using newFixedThreadPool of executer service. Once the job is done we are  shuttingdown the executer.

When this job deployed in production unix server, after few days of running it hanged.Through the logs we see that all executer threads have finished their job but after executing shutdown it got hanged. I assume in this case,executer has not proprly shut down and since we are checking if it's terminated in a for loop.That loop could be running indefinately and hence no further processing. Please share your thoughts what could be the other reason.

Code:

```
do {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)!='-'||str.charAt(i)!=','||str.charAt(i)!='.'||str.charAt(i)!='|') {    
            if(str.charAt(i)=='5'||str.charAt(i)=='6'||str.charAt(i)=='7'||str.charAt(i)=='8'||str.charAt(i)=='9') {
                String s=str.substring(i, i+1);
                Runnable worker = new ExecuteThread(s,batchtype);
                executor.execute(worker);
            }
        }
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }
} while(batchtype == 2);
```

To resolve this i have included shutdownNow method now and thinking to remove infinite loop where we are checking if the executer is terminated. Please share your views if the below code would be sufficient to curb the error.

```
do {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)!='-'||str.charAt(i)!=','||str.charAt(i)!='.'||str.charAt(i)!='|') {    
            if(str.charAt(i)=='5'||str.charAt(i)=='6'||str.charAt(i)=='7'||str.charAt(i)=='8'||str.charAt(i)=='9') {
                String s=str.substring(i, i+1);
                Runnable worker = new ExecuteThread(s,batchtype);
                executor.execute(worker);
            }
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();

    // FIX
    try {
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(900,TimeUnit.SECONDS)) { 
            logger.info("Executor did not terminate in the specified time.");
            List<Runnable> droppedTasks = executor.shutdownNow();
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(600,TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
                logger.info("Even shutdownNow did not terminated in the specified time."); 
            }
            logger.info("Executor abruptly shut down. " + droppedTasks.size() + " tasks will not be executed.");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    //while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    //}

    stopTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("Time taken by executer to finish job with batchType "+batchtype+ " in sec " +(stopTime-startTime)/1000);
} while(batchtype==2);// to run batch-2 in daemon mode
```

Execute Thread Code:

```
public class ExecuteThread extends AbstractMaxisBatchSystem implements Runnable {

    private String serverId;
    private int batchtype;

    public ExecuteThread(String s,int batchtype) throws MaxisBatchFatalException {
                this.serverId=s;
                this.batchtype=batchtype;
        }


    private static Logger logger = null;
    static{
        try{
            logger = logger.getLogger(com.maxis.rnb.batch.realReinstatement.FetchNewPayments.ExecuteThread.class);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { }
    }       

    /*public ExecuteThread(String s, int batchtype2) throws MaxisBatchFatalException{
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }*/


    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            if(batchtype==1)
            {   
                logger.info("FetchNewPayment Batch started for serverID: " +serverId);
                FetchNewPayment batch = new FetchNewPayment();
                batch.execute(serverId);
            }
            else if(batchtype==2)
            {
                //do{
                logger.info("ProcessNewPayment Batch started for serverID: " +serverId);
                ProcessNewPayment batch = new ProcessNewPayment();
                batch.execute(serverId);
                //}
                //while(true);
            }
            else if(batchtype==3)
            {
                logger.info("HouseKeeping Batch started for serverID: " +serverId);
                RRHouseKeeping batch = new RRHouseKeeping();
                batch.execute(serverId);
            }

        }
         catch (MaxisBatchFatalException e)
            {
             logger.error("ServerId: "+serverId+":"+e.getMessage(), e);
            // System.exit(EXIT_FATAL);
             //throw new MaxisBatchFatalException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: **Never do this `while (!executor.isTerminated())`**. That is what [`ExecutorService.awaitTermination()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) is for. Busy waiting is (almost) always wrong. You also have a busy wait here `while(batchtype==2)`.

Comment: Please show us your `ExecuteThread` - how do you shut _that_ down. The `ExecutorService` cannot shutdown unless its threads are idle. `shutdownNow` only works if the threads are interruptible.

Comment: isTerminated was used to ensure all threads got terminate before creating a fresh threadPool in next iteration.Now we are waiting for shutdownNow to complete in 10 min if shutdown not complete in 15 min.Will there be any case where shutdownNow even not able to terminate?. Execute thread is a runnable class. how would we make sure if threads are interruptible..

Comment: Use, I understand why you used `isTerminated` but it's still busy waiting. It ties down one CPU core doing absolutely nothing. A whole core at 100% for no reason. On a server this is unconscionable. As for your `ExecuteThread`, you will need to post its code - how you keep it alive and how you allow it to be stopped.

Comment: ya i understand your concern..thats why i have commented it in new code. below is the executerThread Code.I assume the threads will be stopped as soon we call executer.shutdown().In executeThread i am just calling some other buisness classes.

Comment: Added code in the main question..

Comment: Presumably `batch.execute` has an infinite loop in it? This loop needs to somehow be stoppable. In Java there is no way to terminate a `Thread` that is doing something.

Comment: P.S. a `switch` statement would be _so much_ neater here.

Comment: Yes Boris..use of switch could be better. but batch.execute does not have any infinite loop within. rather we see the programe was running fine for few days and completing all tasks.